# React Native this.props.navigation.navigate is not working when using it in createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I have my app structured in a way that it has a bottom tab navigator. Currently I have only two tabs. Home screen and Settings. The navigation is defined like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation"
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

import HomeTab from './HomeTab'
import SettingsTab from './SettingsTab'

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen: HomeTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
          <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
        )
    }
  },
  Settings:{
    screen: SettingsTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
          <Icon name="ios-settings" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
        )
    }
  }
},
{
  //router config
  initialRoutName: 'Home',
  order: ['Home', 'Settings'],
  //navigation for complete tab navigator
  navigationOptions:{
    tabBarVisible:true
  },
  tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor:'red',
    inactiveTintColor:'grey'
  }
});
```

in my **HomeTab** I have defined a FlatList and for each of the list items I wanted to add **onPress** event. To do so, I decided to use [navigation prop reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html). In order to do that I have implemented this component as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    FlatList,
    Image,
    ActivityIndicator,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ToastAndroid
} from "react-native";

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export class HomeTab extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        dataSource: [],
        isLoading: true
    }
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 3 }}
            onPress = {() => {this.props.navigation.navigate("ComeHere")}}>
            <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40, margin: 5 }}
            source={{ uri: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/IconsLandVistaMapMarkersIconsDemo/256/MapMarker_Marker_Outside_Azure.png' }}
            />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'green' }}>
                    {item.city}, {item.zipCode}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, marginBottom: 15 }}>
                    {item.address}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'center', marginRight: 10}}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                    ({item.numberOfMailItems})
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
  }

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
        <View
            style={{height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        </View>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // Fetch some server data
  }

  render(){
    return (
      this.state.isLoading
      ?
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="green" animating />
      </View>
      :
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList style={{marginTop: 30}}
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.mailboxId}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default HomeTab;
```

And when I click an item, nothing happens. The issue is not that the event is not being triggered because when I add **console.log('something')** there it works.

Interesting thing here is that when I add this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))
```

to the **onPress** event I get the following:

> {"navigation":{"state":{"key":"Home","routeName":"Home"},"actions":{}}}

I mean, I can not see **.navigate** defined there at all.

You can see the snack of it here: https://snack.expo.io/HJuo0e5ZE

When I start it there I get an error saying:

> Device: (3:3587) Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing
>   for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app
>   container directly. More info:
>   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

When I tried to apply what is described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html) (wrapped up by createBottomTabNavigator into the createAppContainer) I started to receive an error saying that

> (0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer) is not a function (In
>   '(0,_reactNavigation.createAppContainer)(AppNavigator)','(0,_reactNavigation.createAppContainer)'
>   is undefined)

Comment: are You using react-navigation v3?

Comment: npm show react-navigation version => returns 3.0.9

Comment: And what You have in console log? There is error about missing `navigate` functions? `JSON.stringify` will not show you functions. IMO it's problem with not existing component name in you code. You try to go to `ComeHere` but there is no route like that in navigation. Change it to `Settings`. And be sure that You create new app container - there was BC break between v2 and v3 releases.

Comment: If I do console.log(this.props.navigation.navigate) It returns 'undefined'. And when I try to execute it nothing happens. 'ComeHere' is an existing component in the same folder. What do you mean by "Create new app container"?

Comment: checkout new docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html. Important part: `export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);`. Before You had to export only navigator.

Comment: I noticed something interesting here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html. The example is with a stack navigator but I have the feeling same applies also for tab navigator. It clearly says: "If we call this.props.navigation.navigate with a route name that we haven't defined on a stack navigator, nothing will happen". The problem is that even when I try to make navigate to a component which is in the same tab navigator it is still not working. onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate("SettingsTab")}}

Comment: Can you put this issue on snack?

Comment: I have updated my post. By the end of it I have added a link to the snack. It seems like I must set up my app container directly which I don't really know how to do. I am quite new to react native.

Comment: Check my edited snack - https://snack.expo.io/HkI5jm9-E App runs ok, and you can switch tabs.

Comment: I can see that it tries to navigate but snack device crashes then. It says : Uncaught error. java.lang.Double can not be cast to java.lang.String. Anyway, I tried the same approach on my laptop locally and I am getting an error described at the end of my edited question